# GLSL Vertex Shader Compilation Error

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

This is my following Error which is ERROR #160 in GLSL.

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
out vec4 pos;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    pos = position;
}
```

and this is the error which was created when trying to compile this GLSL program.

```
ERROR: Vertex Shader Program Compilation Failed! Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:13: error(#160) Cannot convert from: "in highp 3-component vector of vec3" to: "default out highp 4-component vector of vec4"
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

I have no knowledge on debugging GLSL so if there is anyone who can help it would e much appreciated.

Comment: Fixing a compile error is not "debugging".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your error is pretty clear. Since you assign `position` to `pos`, and `pos` is a `vec4` while `position` is a `vec3`, and there is no implicit conversion for this, the compiler complains. To fix this, simply create a `vec4` from you `position`, e.g.

```
pos = vec4(position, 1.0f);
```

However, you should think about why you would need a `vec4` for your position down the pipeline, or whether having `pos` be a `vec3` would be sufficient or not.

Comment: I am the most blind person ever... Thank you for pointing this out for me, I was focusing so much on the gl_Position line.

Comment: @AaronSharp Don't worry, happens to everyone from time to time ;)